# Ansible lineinfile insert after every match

Tags: ansible

I would like to use the Ansible `lineinfile` module (or something similar) to insert a line after *every* match of a particular regular expression (`lineinfile` will only insert after the last match).

This seems so simple. I swear I tried my Google-fu first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses Ansible's `replace` module with a negative lookahead regex to ensure idempotency.

```
vars:
  find_this: "Row in the file"
  insert_this: "New line to be inserted"
  filename: "path/to/foo_file.txt"

tasks:
  - name: multiline match and insert
    replace: >
      dest={{ filename }}
      regexp="^({{ find_this }}\n)(?!{{ insert_this }})"
      replace="\1{{ insert_this }}\n"
```

Comment: nice, I was about to fix my answer with something like this but you beat me to it!

Comment: Nice, I was just putting together a perl one-liner, thought that `lineinfile` might not be able to do a negative lookahead.`perl -i -pe 'BEGIN{undef $/; $c="";} $c=s/(after_this)(?!\ninsert_this)/${1}\ninsert_this/smg; END{ print "CHANGED" if $c}' testfile`. You could use this with `command` or `shell` module, above would print "CHANGED" to stdout if it replaced at least 1 line so you would need to do something like `register: result` and `changed_when: "'CHANGED' in result.stdout"`. This works too but your solution is WAY more simple :)